# How to replace full substring in Netezza

Tags: string, replace, netezza

Netezza sql manual say there is translate(s, from, t) function while this function will replace each character in 'from' to corresponding character in 't', for example: translate(‘
12345’,’14’,’ax’) returns ‘a23x5’.

but if I want to replace 'full' string, for example: translate('123135', '12', 'ab') returns 'ab3135'. how to make it?

Answer (score 4):

`Replace` is not a built in function in `Netezza` however if you have the [SQL Extensions Toolkit installed](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ntz/v7r0m3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.nz.sqltk.doc/c_sqlext_text_utility.html)  then you can use the following functions.

```
select sql_functions..replace('123135', '12', 'ab')
select sql_functions..regexp_replace('123135', '12', 'ab')
```